How to make SwiftUI QR Code generation faster?
I am generating a QR code in swift like this
struct HandOverView: View {
    let store: StoreOf<LogicReducer>
    @State var qrCode: Image?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(systemName: "square.fill")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 350, height: 350)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
            if let qrCode = qrCode {
                qrCode
                    .interpolation(.none)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            } else {
                Text("No QR Code available")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.red)
        .onAppear {
            UIScreen.main.brightness = 1.0
            
            do {
                let result = try StateSnapshot.createStateSnapshot(state: store.state)
                
                qrCode = generateQRCode(from: result)
                
            } catch {
                print("Catch: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> Image? {
        let context = CIContext()
        let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
        
        filter.message = Data(string.utf8)

        if let outputImage = filter.outputImage {
            if let cgImage = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) {
                return Image(uiImage: UIImage(cgImage: cgImage))
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}

I measured the time and the generateQRCode function takes about 2 seconds. My QR code has about 800-900 characters. It took the same time when it wasn't as optimized and was 2500 characters. I can optimize if further to make at about 500-600, but not less, since that is my app logic. Also, I don't think that the size 800-900 is too much.
What is your experience with this and do you have any tips to make this faster? Thanks.

It's very hard to tell in the abstract. I suggest running a release version of your app in the Instruments app's time profiler and seeing where it is spending the bulk of the time.
At a glance the most obvious thing to try would be caching your CIContext and your qrCodeGenerator and reusing them between calls, but without profiling your code it's hard to know if that would have a meaningful impact on performance.
My guess is that the bulk of the time is spent in the Core Image filter. You might find a third party library that creates QR codes faster.
